# Highlight a list item without highlighting it's children (another UL) in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, parent-child, selector

I'm trying to apply a hover effect to a UL, but the UL which is a child of one list item also gets the effect, which I don't want. I tried all sorts of things, for instance using the > sign and the .not() selector, but without succes.

Here's my (simplified) HTML:

```
        <ul id="menu">
            <li class="menubox"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="menubox"><a href="#">Over Ons</a></li>
            <li class="menubox"><a href="#" id="varianten">Producten</a>
                <ul id="menu_varianten">
                    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menubox"><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Some snippets of CSS that might be relevant:

```
#menu {
position: relative;
width: 250px;
}

ul#menu{
list-style: none;
margin-left: 0;
padding-left: 0;
}

ul#menu li a{
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
height: 40px;
}

#menu_varianten{
list-style: none;
display: none;
margin-left: 0;
padding-left: 0;
}

ul#menu_varianten li a{
padding-left: 4em;
height:30px;
}
```

And here's the jQuery:

```
$("ul#menu > li").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({fontSize:"1.4em"}, 150);
    },
    function() {
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({fontSize:"1.0em"}, 150);
    });
```

I also tried the selector ("ul#menu > li").not("#menu_varianten"), but it doesn't work unfortunately. Someone with ideas?

Comment: Wouter, you should go to jsfiddle.net and put your html/css/js in the appropriate panes, and then we can see a live demo. Very cool site!

Comment: Thanks MrBoJangles, I've heared of the site, but never tried it. Thanks to all the solutions here I'll definitely try it next time before asking and also use it in future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try only expanding the first anchor.

Leave your HTML and CSS as they are and change the javascript to:

```
$("ul#menu li").hover(

function() {
    $(this).find('a').first().stop(true, true).animate({
        fontSize: "1.4em"
    }, 150);
}, function() {
    $(this).find('a').first().stop(true, true).animate({
        fontSize: "1.0em"
    }, 150);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RCtFU/1/

Comment: +1, this keeps the parent menu item enlarged also, a nice bonus.

Comment: This is a nice solution, but please post the content of the solution here instead of only on another site.

Comment: @eykanal, Thanks.  Your solution with the use of :not uses less selectors I believe as it doesn't use .find() but I assumed the parent was supposed to stay enlarged.

Comment: @patrick dw: Good idea, I have added the javascript to the solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gazler, great stuff. Simple and elegant solution. Indead it's nice to keep the parent enlarged.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to make each submenu a *sibling* of each parent. CSS inherits, so this would be a pretty simple avoidance of the problem.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/RCtFU/

```
<li class="menubox">
    <a href="#" id="varianten">Producten</a>
</li>
<li class="menubox">  <!-- probably want to change the class -->
    <ul id="menu_varianten">
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

You'll need to do some further adjustments *(different classes, etc.)* to distinguish between menus and submenus.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Patrick. I think your solution has one disadvantage though, in the way that all the submenu items are together seen as one big list item of the parent list (as seen in jsFiddle). To bypass this you'll need more code, so I think I'll go for Gazler's answer. But thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the css3 [`:not()`](http://kilianvalkhof.com/2008/css-xhtml/the-css3-not-selector/) selector:

```
$("ul#menu > li :not(ul)").hover(
function() {
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
        fontSize: "1.4em"
    }, 150);
}, function() {
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
        fontSize: "1.0em"
    }, 150);
});
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eykanal/KJ7FN/).

Comment: Thanks for the fast reaction and your advice on using the :not() selector, but my submenu is still animating, also in jsFiddle.